# How to set up a correct creation date with PDFBox?

Tags: java, timezone, metadata, pdfbox

I'm learning how to generate PDF with PDFBox. So far, I managed to create the document and to modify basic meta data.

I do have a problem with the date of creation, though. I tried many things, this being the most logical one:

```
//My PDDocument is called "document".
PDDocumentInformation info = document.getDocumentInformation();
info.setCreationDate(Calendar.getInstance());
```

The result, when right-clicking on the generated PDF and choosing "properties" is `mar 28 jun 2011 12:28:36 CEST`. (`mar` stands for "mardi", Tuesday in French). My problem is that the correct time should be 12:28:36 **GMT+1**.

When I print `System.out.println(Calendar.getInstance());`, it returns `(...)zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="Europe/Zurich",(...)` (Full content on demand), which is correct!

So, where is the problem?

Comment: just for kicks...did you ever ask the Calendar what its ZoneOffset is? I think you have to cast to GregorianCalendar first.

Comment: @Chris Aldrich Thanks for the hint, but the problem is really with PDFBox. I checked and double-checked the content of `Calendar.getInstance()`: date, hour, time zone, offset, ... Everything is correct and matches the expected results **until** I send it to the `PDDocumentInformation`.

Comment: Why it should be GMT+1? If you run it in france during dst, local time should be GMT+2. And GMT+2 is same as CEST.

Comment: @User1 \*SELF-SLAP\*! I mistook **CEST** with **CST** (UTC - 6 hours)... Oh! Am I silly or am I silly? What about writing a very nice answer that I could accept?

Comment: @User1 I repeat: please answer my question with an **answer**, not a **comment**, so you can be rewarded with 250 reputation points that directly come from my reputation bag...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no problem in you code.
If you run it in france during dst, local time should be GMT+2. And GMT+2 is same as CEST.